# Modeling low poly bush

Tags: modeling

I am planning on modeling a low poly nature collection, but I can't find a way to make a low poly bush like the one in the image below.

[image]

If anyone could mention the steps or make/find a video tutorial to the process of making a low poly bush like the one in the image, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is my result with about 5 minutes of work. Note that I used *Cycles Render*, as it is much better for the scene showed in your question.

[image]

### Modeling the Scene Minus the Berries

The key to this is *Icosphere*s, which you can add using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh > Icosphere*. Add an *Icosphere*. Key <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Toolshelf* and make sure there is only *1* subdivision.

[image]

I scaled all of my *Icosphere*s down on the *Z-Axis* by a factor of *0.7* by keying <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>. I then rotated to *Top Orthographic View* through <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>, then <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>. From there, used <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate, <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, and <kbd>G</kbd> to drag them around appropriately.

I also added an *Icosphere* of *1* subdivision, which I dragged behind the camera and out of view.

Lastly, I added a ground plane, scaled up just enough so that it fills the camera view.

### Materials

The lone *Icosphere* behind the camera got a *Diffuse BSDF* with *Hex: FF0000*.

The bushes got a *Diffuse BSDF* with *Hex: 57E746*. Note that you can add the material to one bush, select all of the others, select the one with the material, key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, and select *Materials* to copy the materials from one bush to the rest.

The ground got a *Diffuse BSDf* with *Hex: 296C27*

### Berries

Select one of the five *Icosphere*s that should have berries on it. Go to the *Properties panel > Particle Systems tab* and add a new particle system. Use these settings, but note that *Icosphere.010* should be the name of your red materialed *Icosphere*.

[image]

Select all of the bushes that should have berries, then select the one that you added the particle system to. Use this feature:

[image]

### Lighting

Select the default *Point* lamp. Change to the following settings. Note that the *Color:* is *Hex: FFFECC*

[image]

Here is the .blend file:

[image]